# Decode Base64 in C# (Either string Encrypted or not)

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to decrypt the string in base64 format. I have some data in encrypt format and some in normal text. First I need to check the string is in encrypted or not. If its in encrypted format then decrypt the string. If its in normal text then show the text as it is.
Here is my code:-

```
public static string DecryptConnectionString(string connectionString)  
{
    string result = "";

    bool app = false;

    app = IsBase64String(connectionString);
    if (app == true)
    {
        Byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(connectionString);
        string decryptedConnectionString = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
        result = decryptedConnectionString;
    }
    else if (app == false)
    {
        result = connectionString;
    }

    return result;       
}

public static bool IsBase64String(string s)
{
    s = s.Trim();
    return (s.Length % 4 == 0) && Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$", RegexOptions.None);

}
```

This code not working fine somtimes it works but somtimes not. If I write "test" then it shows like this "??". Can any one help??

Comment: "This code not working" is my favorite error description.

Comment: Its Typo error, I knw "This code is not working"  Can u help me to solve the above decode string problem???

Comment: The problem is not that you missed the word "is". The problem is that saying "my code is not working" does not give any information about what happens and how you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I have encrypted data in DB, but some data are in normal text. Now if I entered the dummy text like "test" so, by using the above method its showing "??". The issue is, if the string is in encrypt format then decrypt the string and if not then show the results as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the encoding.
In the sample above you use ASCII. Normally when using .net Variables u have UTF-8 string.
For this I recommend you to read [Joel about the basics of unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

You have to always use the encoding with which the string was created.
When you convert the byte data to a string and you don't have the correct encoding, chars which can't be mapped, will return unexpected Chars. (Like ?)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to Base64 decode and catch an exception if it cannot be decoded?

```
string DecryptConnectionString(string connectionString)
{
   string result;

    try
    {
        Byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(connectionString);
        result = decrypt(b);
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        result = connectionString;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: here in this, wht is "decrypt(b);"??

Comment: @Shri: In this example, I assume the base64 string contains an encrypted representation of the connection string. The decrypt() function would be a generic decrypting utility used to obtain the clear string from the encrypted byte[]. You can use whatever function returns the clear text connection string in its place (`System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString()` or other). Hope this helps.